# Erro: Could not find or load main class solucao

Tags: java

Estou treinando para OBI e estou pegando os exercícios em seu site e enviando para executar nele também, porém meu código esta dando erro:

> Error: Could not find or load main class solucao

"*Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal solucao*"
e no meu terminal também, por quê será?

```
package treinamento;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author mrminerin
*/
public class solucao {

public static void main (String[]args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    String [] pedacos = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
    int [] pedacos2 = new int[pedacos.length];
    int pedaco = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < pedacos.length; i++) {
        pedacos2[i] = Integer.parseInt(pedacos[i]);    
        pedaco += pedacos2[i];      
    }
    System.out.println(pedaco - n);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Fiz alguns testes com sua classe e consegui rodá-la.

Deve tomar cuidado na forma como executa sua classe, se tentar chamá-la dentro da pasta treinamento não vai conseguir rodar.

```
 ── treinamento
    ├── solucao.class
    └── solucao.java
```

Precisa chamar fora da pasta da seguinte forma `java treinamento.solucao`.

Se quiser executar diretamente dentro da pasta treinamento, pode remover a declaração de pacote no início do arquivo, dessa forma, dentro da pasta treinamento você vai conseguir rodar com `java solucao`.

Obs.: Nome de classes em java são escritos de outra [forma](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: Sim, eu sei que deve ser maiúsula, mas eles pedem dessa forma.

Comment: @MrMinerin nesse caso é "costume", a única obrigação mesmo é ter o mesmo nome do arquivo

Comment: @MrMinerin se a resposta lhe ajudou, pode marcá-la como [aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/)